# Is Propagation Delay affected by signal frequency?

Tags: buffer, lvds

I'm using some line drivers(lvds) on a project and I have two signals that are propagating consistently differently. Signal A is about ~71Mhz and arrives consistently slower than Signal B which is on the order of 20-25Mhz. (Note: signal A is spi clk and signal B is the MOSI line)

Is this a pretty common correlation?

Edit: SPI clock is ~71Mhz, this is doing some really fast data sampling.
and the line drivers are propagating through cat5 cable.

Comment: Can you quantify what you are seeing? Are the slew rates on your signals different? Because most line drivers (and digital logic in general) don't have frequency dependent propagation delays, but slew rate dependent ones.

Comment: Two *hundred* MHz SPI clock?

Comment: What length cable? What cable type?

Comment: Need a lot more detail than given so far.  How do you terminate ? what driver & receivers used, How is skew measured?

Comment: Your data rate is higher than clock frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the CLK and the MOSI/MISO signals were on two different LVDS driver chip sand the the chip-to-chip skew was greater than feasible for the clock-rate.

Answer (score 3):

Propagation delay is affected by frequency and this is due to skin effect actually affecting the inductance of the cable. [Here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CD0QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fve2azx.net%2Ftechnical%2FCoaxialCableDelay.pdf&ei=RZ9bUtqrBYm-0QXipoHIAg&usg=AFQjCNFcZSKsHk_91wv8nRu8dToh99Ijnw&bvm=bv.53899372,d.d2k) is a pretty interesting document on the matter and here is a small extract of calculated delay versus frequency: -

[image]

Comment: Not only that, but any filter-like response in the circuitry will likely have excess delay in the band edges. Also, we really don't know anything about the layout of this project. Could also be line length because not only is stbtra talking about different frequencies, but different pins as well.